# Magento product image is not visible in frontend

Tags: .htaccess, magento, magento-1.9

Well. I am working on my first magento web site.I am using `magento V1.9.2.4` with `luxury theme V1.2.4`
Its all working fine but Product image.(I am working on localhost xampp )

I uploaded Images trough Catalog -> manage product -> myProduct -> Images -> upload image. Then selected the image Base image, Small image, Thumbnail in the image option.

As it wasnt visible by this so i changed `php_value memory_limit 512M` in `.htaccess` file in my root. this method is not worked.

As I am working on windows i tried to give full permissions to the media folder in the root. still nothing

I also checked if Image attribute have scope global.

I tried using almost all image sizes viz 100X100 200X200 400X400... but still its not working.

what i have to do in this case?

If it helps when i upload 'x' number of images in my back-end. Magento displays 'x' number of product images thumbnails(dummy image) in my front-end product landing page

**Edit::**

I Narrow Down the problem

in here resize function if I give manual height and width It shows image fine. what is the problem with it now?

like this `resize($size[100], $size[100]);`

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize($size['width'], $size['height']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
```